# supervisor child process not reading environment variable

Tags: linux, go, makefile, debian, supervisord

In my go program, I'm using `os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")` to grab the environment variable `DB_PASSWORD`.
While in development, I use `godotenv` and GNU Make to build and start the program. In production, I'm using supervisor to manage the process (basically for its daemonizing and auto-restart capabilities).

But with supervisor, my go program is unable to access any environment variables (set using export key='value').

I've checked out [supervisor with environment variables](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=environment%20variables#environment-variables) section and it's still not working.
I've done `supervisorctl reread` and `supervisorctl update`, still no luck.
How can I get supervisor child process (my program) to read environment variables

```
[program:program_name]
command=/var/www/program_name/bin/program_name -environment production -port 4041 --DB_PASSWORD=%(ENV_DB_PASSWORD)s
directory=/var/www/program_name
environment=DB_PASSWORD=value-here
autorestart=true
autostart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/program_name/logs/supervisord.log
stderr_logfile=/var/www/program_name/logs/supervisord_err.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
logfile_backups=3
loglevel=info
```

Comment: "my go program is unable to access any environment variables" meaning what? `os.Getenv` returns an empty string?

Comment: by manual variables must be inside double quotes and comma separated, have You tried: `environment="DB_PASSWORD=something","DB_USER=root"`

Comment: @Adrian, yes `os.Getenv' returns an empty string

Comment: I'm not sure `--DB_PASSWORD=%(ENV_DB_PASSWORD)s` would work with `environment`.  `environment` manual entry specifically says it sets it in the command's environment, but not supervisors.  Yet supervisor would have to interpolate there.  Also, that command line variable is inferior to ENV (shows up in `ps`).  Maybe irrelevant since you say the env is empty too

Comment: @num8er, I think the actual syntax is `environment=DB_PASSWORD="something",DB_user="root"` as highlighted in [the official documentation](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment)

Comment: @Ercross oops, typo :D

Comment: Doc specifically says the quotes aren't necessary but recommended in all cases.  Since we don't know what the db password is, it could well be that the password contains special characters

Comment: @DanielFarrell, even with an alphanumeric password and it still doesn't work.